# Is it possible to add a button to an empty MainActivity in android?

Tags: android, button, android-activity, main-activity

I have an empty Activity_main layout. I want to add a number of buttons that have to be a certain % of the screen width and for this reason I want to add them programmatically. Every example on this site uses a LinearLayout. Is it possible to add a button directly to the Activity_main?

Thanks.

Comment: The activity has a ViewGroup that is the root view. You have to attach the buttons to that ViewGroup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a [ViewGroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) because it is the base class for layouts and views containers.

If don't want to use a linear layout, you can use a constraint layout. Constraint layouts come with [Guidelines](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/Guideline.html) - they can help you measure a specific percentage of the screen and align buttons (or views) next to them.

[image: guidelines with constraintlayout]

The image above is an example of how guidelines work. The first is a vertical guideline that takes up 25% of the screen (you can think of it as splitting the screen vertically into 4 pieces). The second is a horizontal guideline that takes up 50% of the screen (splitting the screen horizontally into 2 pieces).

> i want to add a number of buttons that have to be a certain % of the screen width

You can achieve this with guidelines. Here's how to do it using only xml:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.chornge.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/vertical_guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.25" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/vertical_guideline" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.50" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/horizontal_guideline" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here's how to create the same effect using only Java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = new ConstraintLayout(this);
    constraintLayout.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    setContentView(constraintLayout);

    /* vertical guideline */

    Guideline verticalGuide = new Guideline(this);
    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams verticalGuideParams =
            new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    verticalGuideParams.guidePercent = 0.25f;
    verticalGuideParams.orientation = LinearLayout.VERTICAL;
    verticalGuide.setLayoutParams(verticalGuideParams);
    verticalGuide.setId(View.generateViewId());
    constraintLayout.addView(verticalGuide);

    /* create button1 and align its left edge to the right edge of vertical guideline*/

    Button button1 = new Button(this);
    button1.setId(View.generateViewId());
    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams button1Params =
            new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    button1Params.leftToRight = verticalGuide.getId();
    button1.setLayoutParams(button1Params);
    constraintLayout.addView(button1);

    /* horizontal guideline */

    Guideline horizontalGuide = new Guideline(this);
    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams horizontalGuideParams =
            new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    horizontalGuideParams.guidePercent = 0.5f;
    horizontalGuideParams.orientation = LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL;
    horizontalGuide.setLayoutParams(horizontalGuideParams);
    horizontalGuide.setId(View.generateViewId());
    constraintLayout.addView(horizontalGuide);

    /* create button2 and align its top edge to the bottom edge of horizontal guideline*/

    Button button2 = new Button(this);
    button2.setId(View.generateViewId());
    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams button2Params =
            new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    button2Params.topToBottom = horizontalGuide.getId();
    button2.setLayoutParams(button2Params);
    constraintLayout.addView(button2);
}
```

**Note**:

- You still need a ViewGroup to be your base class (either LinearLayout or RelativeLayout or ConstraintLayout)
- You can make any View (Button, TextView, EditText, etc) align with another View or ViewGroup using `topToTop` or `topToBottom` or `bottomToTop` or `bottomToBottom` or `leftToLeft` or `leftToRight` or `rightToLeft` or `rightToRight`.
- You can use any percentage you want for your guidelines: 5%, 33.3%, 80% which translates to `0.05f`, `0.333f`, `0.8f`, respectively.